# Display html in cell of datagrid in Dojo

Tags: django, datagrid, hyperlink, dojo, cell

I've problem with DataGrid in Dojo 1.6. I create DataGrid on HtmlStore and I want to put in cells in last column links to some actions. I read on documentation that option escapeHtmlInData="false" can do that, but it doesn't work.I know that is dangerous (XSS attacks), but solution with formatter is not pretty for me. So I don't know why escapeHtmlinData doesn't work. Maybe it's fault of HtmlStore? Maybe someone had a similar problem? I can paste my piece of code but I use Django and dojango.

Comment: I solve my problem. It was fault by HtmlStore. I extend this class and I've override function getValues()

Answer (score 1):

For others:

```
dojo.extend(dojox.data.HtmlStore,{
  getValues: function(item,attribute){

      this._assertIsItem(item);
      var index = this._assertIsAttribute(attribute);
      if(index>-1){
              var text;
              if(item.cells){
                      if({%for value in noEscapeData%}attribute=="{{value}}"{%if not forloop.last %} || {%endif%}{%endfor%}){
                              text = item.cells[index].innerHTML;
                      }else{
                              text = dojox.xml.parser.textContent(item.cells[index]);
                      }
              }else{//return Value for lists
                      text = dojox.xml.parser.textContent(item);
              }
              return [this.trimWhitespace?dojo.trim(text):text];
      }
      return []; //Array
  },
});
```

where `noEscapeData` is array with column name where is not escape data